# Retrieve data from Dynamics Customer Engagement using .Net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We need to retrieve data from Dynamics Customer Engagement from an application developed in `c#` `.Net framework 4.5.2`. We know that for v9.0 of dynamics web API `.Net framework 4.6.2` or higher is needed. What we need to know is if there is any way to query data from dynamics Customer Engagement using our applications requirements (maybe using another API version) because we can't change our `.Net` version for other reasons. We also appreciate help finding some documentation for that.

We try to use an `HttpClient` to make the API calls. The problem is in the authentication step using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory`.

Comment: Could you provide a code sample and an example of the error(s) you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mostly likely cause is the TLS version you are using. TLS 1.2 is required by Dynamics 365.

TLS is supported by the .Net Framework in the following ways

- `.Net Framework 4.0` only supports `TLS 1.0`
- `.Net Framework 4.5` supports `TLS 1.2`, but only by explicit setting the TLS version. (see the code sample below)
- `.Net Framework 4.6` and up natively supports `TLS 1.2`.

If you are forced to use `.Net Framework 4.5` then add the following line of code before you make any HTTP requests.

```cs
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

If code changes are not an option then another approach is to update your registry entries with PowerShell scripts. This would have to be done on every device that is running the application. (Azure may pose an issue however).

**64 bit**

```bsh
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

**32 bit**

```bsh
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

The first option is by far the easiest approach.

Comment: No worries mate 